# Multiple selection tags to filter the cards or images in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have been looking a lot and trying to solve this little logic that is very complicated for me, filtering the data with the selection labels and inputs of a certain range such as price.

The problem is the search filtering: I need that if when I price in houses it shows me the houses and if I price in the next select sale or rent, it shows me the real data. the same with the price.

I am having a hard time understanding how I would do this correctly. I would assume some kind of for loop to get each select tag and then get the current option value in each select tag and only display the list items if they meet the select option value criteria.

I would appreciate any help on how I could achieve this!

```js
const optionTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
const filterProducts =
  document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for (i = 0; i < optionTabs.length; i++) {
  optionTabs[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const filter = e.target.dataset.filter;
    console.log(filter);
    filterProducts.forEach((properties) => {
      if (filter == "all") {
        properties.style.opacity = "1";
        properties.style.visibility = "visible";
      } else if (properties.classList.contains(filter)) {
        properties.style.opacity = "1";
        properties.style.visibility = "visible";
        properties.style.order = "-1";
      } else {
        properties.style.opacity = "0";
        properties.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="properties__filters">
  <span class="properties__filters--txt">Tipo 
                                 dePropiedad</span>
  <select name="type" id="select__type" placeholder="Propiedad">
    <option value=".">Tipos</option>
    <option value="1">Casas</option>
    <option value="2">Departamentos</option>
    <option value="3">Fincas & Casas de Campo</option>
    <option value="4">Terrenos</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="properties__filters">
  <span class="properties__filters--txt">Categoría de 
                              Propiedad:</span>
  <select name="category" id="select__category" class="custom- 
                              select sources" placeholder="Categoría">
    <option value=".">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">Venta</option>
    <option value="2">Alquiler</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="properties__filters">
  <span class="properties__filters--txt">Precio:</span>
  <div class="properties__filters--price">
    <div class="filters__price--prev">
      <span class="price__txt">Desde:</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Min">
    </div>
    <div class="filters__price--next">
      <span class="price__txt">Hasta:</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Max">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card  ">
  <div class="card__images">
    <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html">
      <img src="bienes/images/casa_calderon.jpeg">
    </a>
    <div class="card__images--info ">
      <p>EN VENTA</p>
      <p>CASA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card__images--icons">

      <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html" class="fas fa- 
                                    camera">
        <p>7</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="properties__content">
    <h3 class=" properties__content--title ">Hermosa Casa en Calderón </h3>
    <p class=" properties__content--txt ">HERMOSA CASA DE DOS PLANTAS.CUENTA CON: Departamentos sala...
      <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html">
                                    [detalle]</a>
    </p>
    <div class="properties__content--resume">
      <div class="span__icons">
        <span><i class=" fas fa-bed "></i> 3</span>
        <span><i class=" fas fa-bath "></i> 2</span>
        <span><i class=" far fa-clone "></i> 249 m²</span>
      </div>
      <div class=" link-details "><a href=" Bienes/casa-en- 
                                calderon.html ">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" properties__content--price ">
      <p class=" content__price--money ">$ 135,000.00</p>
      <p class=" content__price--description ">Negociables</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card  ">
  <div class="card__images">
    <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html">
      <img src="bienes/images/casa-independiente-las- 
                            casas.jpeg">
    </a>
    <div class="card__images--info ">
      <p>EN VENTA</p>
      <p>CASA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card__images--icons">

      <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html" class="fas fa-camera">
        <p>9</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="properties__content">
    <h3 class=" properties__content--title ">Casa Independiente en Venta </h3>
    <p class=" properties__content--txt ">CASA DE OPORTUNIDAD INDEPENDIENTE.CUENTA CON: Dormitorios sala...
      <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html">
                                    [detalle]</a>
    </p>
    <div class="properties__content--resume">
      <div class="span__icons">
        <span><i class=" fas fa-bed "></i> 3</span>
        <span><i class=" fas fa-bath "></i> 1</span>
        <span><i class=" far fa-clone "></i> 252 m²</span>
      </div>
      <div class=" link-details "><a href=" Bienes/casa- 
                                     independiente-las-casas.html">Ver
                                        más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" properties__content--price ">
      <p class=" content__price--money ">$ 240,000.00</p>
      <p class=" content__price--description ">Negociables</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand this instruction: `when I price in houses it shows me the houses and if I price in the next select sale or rent, it shows me the real data`

Comment: Well! I want to know how to filter properties in real estate, either with checkbox or selectbox. Where it shows me by types (houses), categories (sale or rent) and city and price.

Comment: What do you expect to get when you do `const optionTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".option");` ? It is supposed to select all elements with class="option"  - that is likely not what you mean. I expect you want to get the value of the select(s)?

Comment: And selects respond to the change event, not the click event

Comment: I am a bit lost on the subject, that fragment I tried to do but it is difficult for me. If you could help me I would appreciate a lot

Comment: If I select `Casas` what am I supposed to select the object on? You do not have a card with class="Casas" for example or data-type="1"

Comment: Yes, but I took it away because it gave me problems, so the difficulty for me that I am starting is this type of real estate filtering.

Comment: I am sorry brother! If it is difficult for me that I am starting in this world of programming, if you could help me I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I'm trying. I will post something

Comment: thanks brother! You help me a lot with this, since in Spanish I can't find anything similar and I don't want to damage the design code by doing it with databases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added data-type and data-category to each card

I did not necessarily use the correct type and category, that is up to you.

I wrapped the filters in a div container and wrapped the cards in a div container

I then delegated the change from the filter container so any change in the filter will trigger a reflow

```js
const cardContainer = document.getElementById("cards");
const resultText = document.getElementById("resultText");
const noResult =  document.getElementById("noResult");
const filterProducts = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")]; // cast to array type
const type = document.getElementById("select__type");
const category = document.getElementById("select__category");
const fromField = document.querySelector(".filters__price--prev input");
const toField   = document.querySelector(".filters__price--next input");
const getPrice = str => str.replace(/[\$ ,]/g,"")
document.getElementById("properties__filters").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  resultText.classList.add("hide")
  const typ = type.value;
  const cat = category.value;
  let from = +fromField.value;
  let to = +toField.value;
  if (to===0) to=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  const filterTexts = []
  if (type.value !==".") filterTexts.push(type.options[type.selectedIndex].text)
  if (category.value !==".") filterTexts.push(category.options[category.selectedIndex].text)
  filterTexts.push(`from $${fromField.value || 0} to ${toField.value ? `$${toField.value}` : "no upper limit"}`)

  filterText.innerHTML = `You searched for ${filterTexts.join(" - ")}`;
  filterProducts.forEach(card => {
    const price = getPrice(card.querySelector(".content__price--money").textContent)
    console.log(from,price,to)
    const show = (typ === "." || card.dataset.type === typ) && 
      (cat === "." || card.dataset.category === cat) &&
      (from <= price && to >= price)
      card.classList.toggle("hide", !show)
  })
  resultText.classList.remove("hide");
  const hidden = cardContainer.querySelectorAll(".hide")
  console.log(hidden.length , filterProducts.length)
  noResult.classList.toggle("hide",hidden.length != filterProducts.length)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="properties__filters">
  <div class="properties__filter">
    <span class="properties__filters--txt">Tipo de Propiedad</span>
    <select name="type" id="select__type" placeholder="Propiedad">
      <option value=".">Tipos</option>
      <option value="1">Casas</option>
      <option value="2">Departamentos</option>
      <option value="3">Fincas & Casas de Campo</option>
      <option value="4">Terrenos</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="properties__filter">
    <span class="properties__filters--txt">Categoría de Propiedad:</span>
    <select name="category" id="select__category" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Categoría">
      <option value=".">Todas</option>
      <option value="1">Venta</option>
      <option value="2">Alquiler</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="properties__filters">
    <span class="properties__filters--txt">Precio:</span>
    <div class="properties__filters--price">
      <div class="filters__price--prev">
        <span class="price__txt">Desde:</span>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Min">
      </div>
      <div class="filters__price--next">
        <span class="price__txt">Hasta:</span>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Max">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="resultText" class="hide">Your search: <span id="filterText"></span><p id="noResult"><b>No results</b></p></div>
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card" data-type="1" data-category="1">
    <div class="card__images">
      <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html">
        <img src="bienes/images/casa_calderon.jpeg">
      </a>
      <div class="card__images--info ">
        <p>EN VENTA</p>
        <p>CASA</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__images--icons">

        <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html" class="fas fa-camera">
          <p>7</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="properties__content">
      <h3 class=" properties__content--title ">Hermosa Casa en Calderón </h3>
      <p class=" properties__content--txt ">HERMOSA CASA DE DOS PLANTAS.CUENTA CON: Departamentos sala...
        <a href="Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html">[detalle]</a>
      </p>
      <div class="properties__content--resume">
        <div class="span__icons">
          <span><i class=" fas fa-bed "></i> 3</span>
          <span><i class=" fas fa-bath "></i> 2</span>
          <span><i class=" far fa-clone "></i> 249 m²</span>
        </div>
        <div class=" link-details "><a href=" Bienes/casa-en-calderon.html ">Ver más</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" properties__content--price ">
        <p class=" content__price--money ">$ 135,000.00</p>
        <p class=" content__price--description ">Negociables</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-type="2" dasta-category="1">
    <div class="card__images">
      <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html">
        <img src="bienes/images/casa-independiente-las-casas.jpeg">
      </a>
      <div class="card__images--info ">
        <p>EN VENTA</p>
        <p>CASA</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__images--icons">

        <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html" class="fas fa-camera">
          <p>9</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="properties__content">
      <h3 class=" properties__content--title ">Casa Independiente en Venta </h3>
      <p class=" properties__content--txt ">CASA DE OPORTUNIDAD INDEPENDIENTE.CUENTA CON: Dormitorios sala...
        <a href="Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html">[detalle]</a>
      </p>
      <div class="properties__content--resume">
        <div class="span__icons">
          <span><i class=" fas fa-bed "></i> 3</span>
          <span><i class=" fas fa-bath "></i> 1</span>
          <span><i class=" far fa-clone "></i> 252 m²</span>
        </div>
        <div class=" link-details "><a href=" Bienes/casa-independiente-las-casas.html">Ver más</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" properties__content--price ">
        <p class=" content__price--money ">$ 240,000.00</p>
        <p class=" content__price--description ">Negociables</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brother! It has resolved my question and thank you very much for that, you really made it understandable even for me. Do you know how to also filter the price of the property in a range?, Either from - to. and something else! and if you do not find the result write alog about it that your result was not found. where do i put it?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: thanks bro! You have really been very helpful to me, I just need the information if you can't find something, send you a message, then a little transition, where will you go? ...


Garcia and sorry for asking you so much, you are great!

Comment: no! in Spanish I wanted to say thank you.

Comment: Brother! One more thing, do you know where a small transition would go to show it in a friendly way, I know if I introduce a spinner or something? .. and also if I don't have a property, send me a message ...

gracias!

Comment: You have really helped me a lot! I would like to get paid in some way but I am not so much money ...
but if it is not a very high price it could ..
I still have faults when I find a property it shows me that message and I want it to send me the message "no results have been found"

Comment: OK! sorry and thank you very much for the help!